# Loop through a class with enum array

Tags: vb.net

I have a class where one of the fields is an enum type array:

```
Public Enum InvalidEmailType
    Unkown
    TrailingSpace
    InnerSpace
    TrailingPeriod
    MissingAtSign
    MultipleAtSigns
    FakeEmail
    PhoneExtension
End Enum
Public Class CustomerClass
    Public CustomerName As String
    Public LDCCode As Integer
    Public LDCName As String
    Public LDCAccountNo As String    
    Public Commodity As String
    Public Email As String
    Public ValidEmail As Boolean
    Public Suggestion As String
    Public Errortype = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(InvalidEmailType))
    Public ErrorDescription As String
End Class
```

As I add values to the Errortype Array, I need to write a single ErrorDescription for the user to read easily. The ErrorDescription field works like a summary of all potential errors in 1 word.

But first I need to determine how many instances of InvalidEmailType.Unkown are there.

For this I wrote a function to count the number of unknowns.

**My problem is how to do you loop through the array inside the class and match that to the enum?**

This is what I tried so far:

```
Public Shared Function ErroTypeMessage(customer As CustomerClass) As String
        Dim Instances As Integer = 0
        For Each value In customer.Errortype
            If value. <> InvalidEmailType.Unkown Then 'here is the problem

            End If
        Next
End Function
```

**Update. Here is the new function. I still cannot get an accurate match**

```
  Public Shared Function ErroTypeMessage(customer As CustomerClass) As String
        Dim Instances As Integer = 0
        ErroTypeMessage = Nothing
        For Each value In customer.Errortype
            If value <> InvalidEmailType.Unkown Then 'does not match properly
                Instances = +1
            Else
                ErroTypeMessage = value.ToString
            End If
        Next
        If Instances > 1 Then
            ErroTypeMessage = "Multiple"
        ElseIf Instances = 1 Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            ErroTypeMessage = "Unkown"
        End If
    End Function
```

**I have solved the problem.**

```
Public Shared Function ErroTypeMessage(customer As CustomerClass) As String
        Dim Instances As Integer = 0
        ErroTypeMessage = Nothing
        Dim temp As String
        For Each value In customer.Errortype
            temp = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(InvalidEmailType), value.ToString), InvalidEmailType)
            If temp <> InvalidEmailType.Unkown Then
                ErroTypeMessage = temp
                Instances += 1
            End If
        Next
        If Instances > 1 Then
            ErroTypeMessage = "Multiple"
        ElseIf Instances = 1 Then
            ErroTypeMessage = CType(ErroTypeMessage, InvalidEmailType).ToString()
        ElseIf Instances = 0 Then
            ErroTypeMessage = "Unkown"
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Post the error if any.

Comment: Can an error type appear more than once?

Comment: Most of the time the ErrorType will be unknown.

This array is currently holding around 10 values, 90% of them will be unknown. But some of them will 2 values that are not unkown, and for that I need to write a summary error description

Answer (score 0):

Your email error variable **can** be an array, but the enum could also be a flag type and you combine errors:

```
<Flags>
Enum InvalidEmailType
    NoError = 0 
    Unkown = 1            ' not needed?
    TrailingSpace = 2
    InnerSpace = 4
    TrailingPeriod = 8
    MissingAtSign = 16
    MultipleAtSigns = 32
    FakeEmail = 64
    PhoneExtension = 128
End Enum
```

In the class:

```
Public Errortype As InvalidEmailType = InvalidEmailType.None
```

In your code to validate the email addy, OR enum values to accumulate errors:

```
Errortype = Errortype Or InvalidEmailType.TrailingPeriod   ' example
```

To test for a condition, use And:

```
If Errtype And InvalidEmailType.FakeEmail = InvalidEmailType.FakeEmail Then
   ' take action here
End if
```

I am not sure how you detect unknown.